# React Konva Transformer Error "Cannot read property 'getStage' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, konvajs, react-konva

I'm using Konva 4.0.18 within a React 16.8. Application, which works well so far in the Standalone (CRA). When integrating this working solution into an existing Application Frame I'm facing an error which appears on transforming the rectangle (and constantly appears on moving the mouse even if the rectangle transformation stopped when clicked again):

> Transformer.js:316 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getStage' of undefined
>       at e._handleMouseMove (Transformer.js:316)
>       at default-passive-events.js:6

[Screenshot of the debugger at the function 'findOne' which returns an 'undefined'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fvB1.jpg)

There is an `Masking`component which imports Konva's `Stage`, `Layout` and `Image` and as well as the `MaskingRectangle` which can be transformed.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import MaskingRectangle from "./maskingRectangle";

const Masking = ({ canvas }) => {
    const stageWrapperRef = useRef(null);
    const [stageWidth, setStageWidth] = useState(600);
    const [stageHeight, setStageHeight] = useState(400);
    const [maskingRectangles, setMaskingRectangles] = useState([]);
    const [shapes, setShapes] = useState([]);
    const [selectedId, selectShape] = useState(null);

    const [Stage, setStage] = useState(null);
    const [Layer, setLayer] = useState(null);
    const [Image, setImage] = useState(null);

    const addRectangle = e => {
        const getRandomInt = max => {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
        };
        let rectX = getRandomInt(100);
        let rectY = getRandomInt(100);
        if (e) {
            const { x, y } = e.currentTarget.getPointerPosition();
            rectX = x;
            rectY = y;
        }

        const rect = {
            x: rectX,
            y: rectY,
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            fill: "rgba(255,0,0,0.4)",
            id: `rect${maskingRectangles.length + 1}`
        };
        const rects = maskingRectangles.concat([rect]);
        setMaskingRectangles(rects);
        const shs = shapes.concat([`rect${maskingRectangles.length + 1}`]);
        setShapes(shs);
    };

    const deleteActiveRectangle = () => {
        setMaskingRectangles(
            maskingRectangles.filter(rect => rect.id !== selectedId)
        );
        setShapes(shapes.filter(shape => shape !== selectedId));
        selectShape(null);
    };

    const onStageClick = e => {
        if (e.target.attrs.className !== "mask-rect") {
            selectShape(null);
        }
    };

    const onStageDblClick = e => {
        const stage = e.target.parent.parent;
        const elem = e.currentTarget;

        if (elem.clickStartShape.attrs.className !== "mask-rect") {
            addRectangle(e);
        }

        if (elem.clickStartShape.attrs.id === selectedId) {
            deleteActiveRectangle();
            stage.container().style.cursor = "crosshair";
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        async function loadKonvaModules() {
            await import("react-konva").then(module => {
                setStage(() => module.Stage);
                setLayer(() => module.Layer);
                setImage(() => module.Image);
            });
        }
        loadKonvaModules();
        const scaleX = stageWrapperRef.current.clientWidth / canvas.width;
        const scaleY = stageWrapperRef.current.clientHeight / canvas.height;
        const scalingFactor = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
        setStageWidth(canvas.width * scalingFactor);
        setStageHeight(canvas.height * scalingFactor);
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="stage-wrapper" ref={stageWrapperRef}>
                <Stage
                    className="stage"
                    width={stageWidth}
                    height={stageHeight}
                    onClick={onStageClick}
                    onDblClick={onStageDblClick}
                >
                    <Layer className="layer1">
                        <Image
                            image={canvas}
                            width={stageWidth}
                            height={stageHeight}
                        />

                        {maskingRectangles.map((rect, i) => {
                            return (
                                <MaskingRectangle
                                    key={i}
                                    shapeProps={rect}
                                    isSelected={rect.id === selectedId}
                                    onSelect={() => {
                                        selectShape(rect.id);
                                    }}
                                    onChange={newAttrs => {
                                        const rects = maskingRectangles.slice();
                                        rects[i] = newAttrs;
                                        setMaskingRectangles(rects);
                                    }}
                                    onMouseEnter={e => {
                                        const stage = e.target.parent.parent;
                                        stage.container().style.cursor = "move";
                                    }}
                                    onMouseOut={e => {
                                        const stage = e.target.parent.parent;
                                        stage.container().style.cursor =
                                            "crosshair";
                                    }}
                                    stageProps={{
                                        width: stageWidth,
                                        height: stageHeight
                                    }}
                                />
                            );
                        })}
                    </Layer>
                </Stage>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Masking;
```

My `MaskinRectangle` componeht looks like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { Rect, Transformer } from "react-konva";

const MaskingRectangle = ({
    shapeProps,
    isSelected,
    onSelect,
    onChange,
    stageProps,
    onMouseEnter,
    onMouseOver,
    onMouseOut,
    onMouseMove
}) => {
    const shapeRef = React.useRef();
    const trRef = React.useRef();

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (isSelected) {
            trRef.current.setNode(shapeRef.current);
            trRef.current.getLayer().batchDraw();
        }
    }, [isSelected]);

    const dragBoundFunc = pos => {
        //Limit Min/Max x,y position
        const stageWidth = (stageProps && stageProps.width) || 800;
        const stageHeight = (stageProps && stageProps.height) || 600;
        const minX = 0;
        const minY = 0;
        const maxX = stageWidth - shapeRef.current.attrs.width;
        const maxY = stageHeight - shapeRef.current.attrs.height;
        const newX = pos.x < minX ? minX : pos.x > maxX ? maxX : pos.x;
        const newY = pos.y < minY ? minY : pos.y > maxY ? maxY : pos.y;

        return {
            x: newX,
            y: newY
        };
    };

    return (
        <>
            <Rect
                className="mask-rect"
                onClick={onSelect}
                onTap={onSelect}
                ref={shapeRef}
                {...shapeProps}
                draggable
                onTouchMove={null}
                onDragEnd={e => {
                    onChange({
                        ...shapeProps,

                        x: e.target.x(),
                        y: e.target.y()
                    });
                }}
                onTransformEnd={e => {
                    const node = shapeRef.current;
                    const scaleX = node.scaleX();
                    const scaleY = node.scaleY();
                    node.scaleX(1);
                    node.scaleY(1);
                    onChange({
                        ...shapeProps,
                        x: node.x(),
                        y: node.y(),
                        width: node.width() * scaleX,
                        height: node.height() * scaleY
                    });
                    e.evt.preventDefault();
                }}
                dragBoundFunc={dragBoundFunc}
                onMouseOver={onMouseOver}
                onFocus={onMouseOver}
                onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter}
                onMouseOut={onMouseOut}
                onBlur={onMouseOut}
                onMouseMove={onMouseMove}
            />
            {isSelected && <Transformer ref={trRef} rotateEnabled={false} />}
        </>
    );
};

export default MaskingRectangle;
```

Some thoughts/guesses:
I wonder why this work perfectly well as a standalone App, but fails when included into an existing HTML Page (which, by the way, includes also libraries like jquery and Angular 1.x).

Maybe you can give me some hints how to search or answer one of these questions:

1. There are  a couple of event handlers (click, mousemove) registered 
   on the body and other elements outside the React App itself, but
   they    shouldn't affect the react app, or am I wrong here?
2. I see the mention    of `default-passive-events` in the error. How this
   might have to do    with the issue (and if so, how could that be
   avoided)?
3. Is ist more    likely that the Konva.js library has an
   issue (see screenshot    attached)

Thanks in advance for any help, comments, suggestions where/how to look

Comment: It looks like at some point `Konva.Transformer` was removed (or destroyed) but it still listens to window events. You may try to set a breakpoint inside `remove()` method of Konva and check if it was executed.